# WSO2 iOS Enrollment - hostname in certificate didn't match: <IP> != <HOSTNAME>

Tags: ios, ssl, wso2

I am receiving the below error when I try to enter my domain, username and password during the iOS enrollment process. I have everything pointing to the domain name of the server, not the IP address. I dont know why its trying to use the IP to enroll the device as everything is changed to domain names in the config files.

Any ideas?

Thanks

> [2016-02-24 15:15:23,556] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.ios.util.OAuthUtils} -  Error occurred
>   while sending 'Post' request due to failure of server connection
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match:  !=

Comment: hi could you share the version of EMM in which you faced this issue

Comment: can you also verify if the certificate is created with the host name. More details can be followed from step 6 point B on the document below https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/General+iOS+Server+Configurations